# Spark - Delimiter not found, how to add a separator in the end of the line?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I'm getting an error when copying data into Redshift. After looking into the `stl_load_errors` table it appeared that the reason is due to `Delimiter not found`.

I'm using a group separator between the dataframe columns and saving the data as a text file:

```
val columns: Array[Column] = salesDF.columns.map(col)
val dataFrame = salesDF.select(concat_ws(String.valueOf(29.toChar), columns: _*)).write.text(outputLocation)
```

The resulting data in a file looks like this:

[image]

After comparing with data from files that load into Redshift successfully, I suspect that the problem is that there is no separator in the very end.

But the delimiter is already passed to `concat_ws`. And I don't quite understand how to achieve this when saving data like above? In other words, how can I add the same separator to the end of every line as well?

Comment: Have you tried a `df.write.option("sep","YOUR_SEPARATOR")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `concat_ws` function will only add a separator in between the values you give. To add an additional separator to the end of each line you can make use of the `concat` function.

```
val sep = String.valueOf(29.toChar)
salesDF.select(concat(concat_ws(sep, columns: _*), lit(sep)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
val columns: Array[Column] = salesDF.columns.map(c => concat(col(c), typedLit(String.valueOf(29.toChar))))
val dataFrame = salesDF.select(concat(columns: _*)).write.text(outputLocation)
```